# How To Give Different Answer For A Specific "arg" In Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So, what I want is a single `@bot.command()` that can reply to both commands of `+commands` and `+commands 2`. So if I say `+commands` it replies with the first list of commands and if I say `+commands 2` it replies with the second list of commands.

What I Have So Far:

```
@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="**__Commands 1:__**", description="Here the Moderation and Regular commands of this bot, the requirements to use them and their nicknames.\n", color=discord.Color.blue())

    embed.add_field(name="**Moderation Commands**", value="`+lock`: Prevents all non-admins from speaking in the channel.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Manage Channel Permissions\n\n`+unlock`: Allows all non-admins to talk in the channel again.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Manage Channel Permissions\n\n`+kick`: Kicks the person that you ping after the command `+kick`.\n**Permissions Required**: Role with kick members permissions required.\n\n`+ban`: Bans the person that you ping after the command `+kick`.\n**Permissions Required**: Role with ban members permissions required.\n", inline=False)

    embed.add_field(name='**Regular Commands**', value='`+announcement`: Sends an announcement to the announcement channel.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Kick Abilities\n**Nicknames**: `+ann`\n\n`+members`: Shows how many people and bots are on the server and their stats.\n**Nicknames**: `+m`\n\n**The permissions requirements assumes that your admins and moderators are trusted people.*', inline=False)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def commands2(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="**__Commands 2:__**", description="Here the fun commands of this bot, the requirements to use them and their nicknames.\n", color=discord.Color.blue())

    embed.add_field(name='**Fun Commands**', value='`+spam`: Sends a spam message.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Kick Abilities\n\n`+say`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+say`.\n**Nicknames**: `+s`\n\n`+bold`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+bold` in bold.\n**Nicknames**: `+b`\n\n`+italic`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+italic` in italics.\n**Nicknames**: `+i`\n\n`+strikethrough`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+strikethrough` crossed out.\n**Nicknames**: `+st`\n\n`+underline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+underline` underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+ul`\n\n`+boldunderline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `boldunderline` bolded and underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+bul`\n\n`+bully`: The bot bullies the person you __ping__ after the command `+bully`.\n\n**The permissions requirements assumes that your admins and moderators are trusted people.*', inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I've seen this somewhere before, I just can't remember, like:

```
@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx, arg):
if {arg} == 2:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="**__Commands 2:__**", description="Here the fun commands of this bot, the requirements to use them and their nicknames.\n", color=discord.Color.blue())

    embed.add_field(name='**Fun Commands**', value='`+spam`: Sends a spam message.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Kick Abilities\n\n`+say`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+say`.\n**Nicknames**: `+s`\n\n`+bold`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+bold` in bold.\n**Nicknames**: `+b`\n\n`+italic`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+italic` in italics.\n**Nicknames**: `+i`\n\n`+strikethrough`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+strikethrough` crossed out.\n**Nicknames**: `+st`\n\n`+underline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+underline` underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+ul`\n\n`+boldunderline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `boldunderline` bolded and underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+bul`\n\n`+bully`: The bot bullies the person you __ping__ after the command `+bully`.\n\n**The permissions requirements assumes that your admins and moderators are trusted people.*', inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This definetly won't work though (I tried), could you tell me what's I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add one more parameter in the command function and then use if-else.

```
@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx, command_number):
    if int(command_number) == 1:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="**__Commands 1:__**", description="Here the Moderation and Regular commands of this bot, the requirements to use them and their nicknames.\n", color=discord.Color.blue())

        embed.add_field(name="**Moderation Commands**", value="`+lock`: Prevents all non-admins from speaking in the channel.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Manage Channel Permissions\n\n`+unlock`: Allows all non-admins to talk in the channel again.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Manage Channel Permissions\n\n`+kick`: Kicks the person that you ping after the command `+kick`.\n**Permissions Required**: Role with kick members permissions required.\n\n`+ban`: Bans the person that you ping after the command `+kick`.\n**Permissions Required**: Role with ban members permissions required.\n", inline=False)

        embed.add_field(name='**Regular Commands**', value='`+announcement`: Sends an announcement to the announcement channel.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Kick Abilities\n**Nicknames**: `+ann`\n\n`+members`: Shows how many people and bots are on the server and their stats.\n**Nicknames**: `+m`\n\n**The permissions requirements assumes that your admins and moderators are trusted people.*', inline=False)
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    elif int(command_number) == 1:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="**__Commands 2:__**", description="Here the fun commands of this bot, the requirements to use them and their nicknames.\n", color=discord.Color.blue())

        embed.add_field(name='**Fun Commands**', value='`+spam`: Sends a spam message.\n**Permissions Required**: Role With Kick Abilities\n\n`+say`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+say`.\n**Nicknames**: `+s`\n\n`+bold`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+bold` in bold.\n**Nicknames**: `+b`\n\n`+italic`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+italic` in italics.\n**Nicknames**: `+i`\n\n`+strikethrough`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+strikethrough` crossed out.\n**Nicknames**: `+st`\n\n`+underline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `+underline` underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+ul`\n\n`+boldunderline`: Makes the bot say the words you said after `boldunderline` bolded and underlined.\n**Nicknames**: `+bul`\n\n`+bully`: The bot bullies the person you __ping__ after the command `+bully`.\n\n**The permissions requirements assumes that your admins and moderators are trusted people.*', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        await ctx.send('Please choose: 1 or 2')
```